# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

When these two flags are added(or set) to a new activity A, A becomes the top of task's back stack and is shown on the screen. Here HOME is pressed, and the screen shows home.
What I want: Then let's go to launcher and select the app's icon, the app comes alive again, the A is gone.
What I am confused: Then let's long press HOME and select the app, the app comes alive again, A is still THERE.

I want A disappeared, however from Launcher or from Recent. How can I make it?

Comment: Please use `adb shell dumpsys activity` and post the contents of the activity stack for the task, once for each scenario (ie: after pressing HOME and relaunching the app (where A is gone) and then again after long-press HOME and A returns). Also post your manifest.

Comment: thank you for sharing a never-used command, let me describe what happened:  
After HOME pressed, the back stack is A1,A2,A3,A(flagged)  
After relaunched from Launcher, it is A1,A2,A3(A is gone)  
After done from long pressed HOME, it is A1,A2,A3,A(A is still there)  

A's manifest is auto-generated by Eclipse, nothing else added, it's only started by A3.startActivity(new Intent(...).add/setFlags(Flags in the titile)). That's all.  
Besides, I dont think it a problem. Just want to know how they can behave uniformly, from Launcher and from Recent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any easy way to do this. You can either exclude your app from the Recent list or save a flag in activity A that if true call finish() in onCreate.

Comment: Look, Android provides a way to clear back stack-top activity(just set flags when started) for coming back from Launcher, but behaves differently from Recent, dont you think it a bit weird? maybe both of us find not the smartest given way?

Comment: I think they mean to have the recent to behave exactly as the last time the app appears, thus they leave the backstack as is.

Comment: I though they would pass the FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY and then in A you can check this flag and called finish() in onCreate but that is not the case.

Comment: yes, you are mostly right, they want task intact when being revisited from Recent, but why not so from Launcher? or why not directly to root ( as flagged NEW TASK & CLEAR TOP) which is more straight, from launcher.  <br/>

you showed a workaround, but finish() might be added onRestart().